# Can I consider interaction effect between two principal components?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, pca, interaction, glmm

I ran a PCA on five variable and got PC1, PC2 as the main axes. Then I want to run a GLMM with binomial distribution to see how these two PCs influence the response variable. My question is if I can put PC1:PC2 (because I think there should be a influence of PC2 on the relationship between PC1 and response variable) in the model? The current result (when putting PC1:PC2 in the model) shows a significance of interaction.

Answer (score 2):

As an interaction term is the product of the individual predictors, your PC1:PC2 interaction includes all 2-way interactions among the original predictors, including quadratic terms in each of them.

First, you should check that you aren't overfitting the data this way. Say that you used cross-validation (CV) to find that 2 principal components provided the best fit in the variance/bias tradeoff that minimizes overfitting. That CV didn't include the subsequent interaction between PC1 and PC2, so just adding the PC1:PC2 interaction subsequently might overfit. The "significance of interaction" that you found so far might just represent overfitting. You should include any post-PCR addition of interactions in your modeling validation, e.g. by CV or bootstrapping, to evaluate that.

Second, recognize that predictions from the model will now involve all 2-way interactions among the original predictors, including quadratic terms in each of them. With a larger number of original predictors than the 5 you have that might become unwieldy. It certainly will be harder to interpret in terms of the original predictors. If there are useful heuristic interpretations of PC1 and PC2, that interpretation issue might not be a big problem.

Third, if you think that interactions among all the predictors might be important, think about different ways to model them. Most directly related to your approach, you could expand your predictor set to include all of the 2-way interactions among the original predictors, including quadratic terms in each of them, in your data matrix *first*. In your situation that wouldn't be much of a problem, as you only would expand your predictors from 5 to 30. Then standard PCR methods on that expanded data set would allow evaluation of the optimal choice of the number of components to retain. Alternatively, a different modeling approach like boosted trees might better capture the major predictors in their original scales while incorporating interactions among them.